# How to modify contiguity matrix in ArcGIS?

Tags: polygon, arcgis-pro, topology, spatial-relationship

Is there any way to modify the contiguity relationships between the polygons in ArcGIS. I am thinking about a topology database that lets the user modify the data on the map? For example, if there is no contiguity between an island and the mainland, you can change it on a topological level.

I have used an AZTool converter which generates an .AAT file which shows the relationships between the polygons in the data and lets the user modify those relationships. However, I do not think it's possible to reload the file to ArcGIS.

[image: .AAT file showing the contiguity between the polygons]

.AAT file showing the contiguity between the polygons

Answer (score 0):

By using Spatial Weights Matrix tool in GeoDa or ArcGIS.